# WPF D3DImage loses front buffer

Tags: wpf, windows-7, directx, slimdx

I am writing code using VS.Net 10 and SlimDX to render 3D content on a D3DImage. It works perfectly under 32 Bit Windows XP. However, after migrating to 64 bit Windows 7 (quad core and 4 GB Ram), the same code does not work any more. The symptom is that after rendering about 10 or 20 times, the D3DImage's IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged event is raised and the property of IsFrontBufferAvailable has a value of false.

I have checked everything I can think of, e.g. RenderCapability.Tier, calling SetBackBuffer, checking the device (in fact it is DeviceEx type) after the front buffer is lost, updating video card driver (nvidia 9500 GT 1G RAM), etc. None of them worked.

One thing that may contribute to the problem is that the image control which uses D3DImage as the source is not created on the GUI thread. I am doing to reduce the work load of the GUI thread to make the application more responsive. Of course, I have been using Dispatcher.Invoke to avoid threading problems. Again, it works perfectly in XP.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a x64 version of the slimdx.dll..  if you are using the x32 version, that could be the problem.

Comment: Tried 32 bit and 64 bit version, tried Any PC, x86, x64 and Mixed Platform configurations and tried a lot of other things. None works. :(